# woocommerce category translation

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, multilingual, wpml, polylang

I'm trying to create a web shop with WooCommerce and Polylang.  When I click the '+' icon in a product category in order to translate it into French, I'm routed to a 'new category' form.

After I created the 'book' category in French ('libre'), I see that the 'book' category contains 8 items, while the 'libre' category contains zero.

Is it a known issue that the relations between items get 'lost in translation' in Polylang / WooCommerce?

Should I try another webshop implementation if I want an internationalizeable web shop, integrated with a web site + blog?

Comment: Just an advice: For WooCommerce multilingual, you have just one really functional option: WPML. All other solutions are incomplete or really complicated to get them work.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec have you tried https://multilingualpress.org/ ? What is your opinion? I have hated WPML every time I've needed to use it.

Comment: @helgatheviking I have try to use the 2 other free challengers on WooCommerce multilingual websites and that was pure nightmare… I have try WPML and bought a global developer lifetime license. Then I have always used WPML for my clients WooCommerce websites without any frustration or big problems since 3 years. **Support is very reactive and accurate**. Also WPML has changed a lot since 1 year. It's not perfect but it works with WooCommerce and almost all plugins and themes. As Multilingualpress is more recent, I haven't try it yet. I will have to try it, but not sure about WooCommerce Needs

Comment: @LoicTheAztec: why not pour that into an answer, so I can upvote it.  It sounds like good advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a WooCommerce multilingual web shop, there is just one really functional option *(may be two*): [WPML](https://wpml.org). All other free solutions (challengers) are incomplete or really complicated to get them work. [WPML](https://wpml.org) is a commercial plugin suite, with a very reactive and accurate support. This plugin is in constant evolution and get really enhanced through major versions. It's not perfect but it works with WooCommerce and almost all plugins and themes.

Apparently there is a new (or recent) commercial challenger that I havent tested yet: [Multilingualpress](https://multilingualpress.org/)… As I haven't test it yet, I can't tell about the level of compatibility with WooCommerce or the support quality.

**[Here you will find a comparison of features and functionalities between all challengers.](https://wpml.org/home/comparing-wpml-free-paid-alternatives)**