# WP PolyLang only translates WooCommerce partially

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, translation, polylang

I have created an account page for WooCommerce ([woocommerce_my_account]) and I have PolyLang installed. When I switch from english to another language, it only translates some of the strings - Sign out, Profile settings and Orders. The other remain in english - Dashboard, Downloads, Addresses, etc., even though they are in the same list. I've checked the woocommerce po files for missing translations, but they all seem to be intact. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please have a look at that: https://wpml.org/home/comparing-wpml-free-paid-alternatives/ and also at this [woocommerce category translation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41663374/3730754). To get a serious and working multilingual WooCommerce web site, Polylang will not do the trick…

Comment: Thanks, I'm almost trying to force custom string translations with Loco Translate.

Answer (score 2):

You can't translate content of posts or pages with something based on `.po` / `.mo` files, because it is only for theme or plugin localisation, but not for multi language content.

> WP PolyLang **will only translates WooCommerce partially**, even using Loco Translate plugin.

For content translation in Wordpress, you can chose between those two:

- **Qtranslate** *free* plugin
- **WPML** *commercial* plugin
- *May be there is actually some new other plugins…*

Each one has its strengths and weaknesses…

---

See: [Comparing translation plugins features regarding WooCommerce](https://wpml.org/home/comparing-wpml-free-paid-alternatives/)