# Shop page is not been translated

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, multilingual, polylang

I'm now using the plugin Polylang, and I currently have two languages: Spanish and eEnglish (default).

All of the pages are redirecting well while changing the language to Spanish, *except* for the "shop" page which is redirecting to the home page.

When I activate the "hide flags if there is no translation" option (it is on the admin menu page) the Spanish flag is not present on the menu, so it is like either WooCommerce or Polylang is not recognizing my shop page translated to Spanish.

I actually **do not want** to create a code to redirect the page, or to create another flag, I just want the "Tienda" page recognized.

Did this happen to you in the past?

Comment: It would be nice if you had read some of the other questions and answers / on this site.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42417293/wp-polylang-only-translates-woocommerce-partially?rq=1) has comments that make it clear that _Polylang will not do the trick (with WooCommerce)_.  You will need to find a different plugin (The comment also has a link to help you find a different translation plugin).

Comment: @cale_b that post it doesn't actually solve my problem, the thing is that I don't understand why shop page can't be translated... I mean, my account page, for example, when I use polylang creates a new page on the other language and assign like a "my account" role? or something so the new page is created and I can have two woocommerce my account pages with the role "my account" (I know that roles is just for users, is just that I don't know what's the name for that)... so... how do I manually assign another "shop" role to other page?

Comment: The point of that post is _you cannot solve your problem with Polylang_.  If you want to understand _why_, contact Polylang.